# Can't move top.links (topLinks) block in Magento

Tags: layout, magento

I'm trying my very best to edit the Magento design the way they want you to (using a local.xml rather than editing the page.xml) but this system is so horrible and convoluted, it's proving to be seriously tricky to do so.

The problem I have now is that I can't seem to move the "top.links" block into another block in the header. At the moment in page.xml this block is within the header block. I've tried absolutely everything in my local.xml to get this to work, I've tried the following edits.

**Remove top.links from header, add inside "Hud" block.**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <!-- Here is where we edit the header block -->
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="top.links" />
            <remove name="top.search" />
            <!-- This is the block that holds the HUD -->
            <block type="page/html" name="hud" as="hud" template="page/html/hud.phtml">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>

</layout>
```

[image]

Note that the links should be inside the brown box (this is the HUD block).

**NOT removing the top.links block from header but adding to Hud block**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <!-- Here is where we edit the header block -->
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="top.search" />
            <!-- This is the block that holds the HUD -->
            <block type="page/html" name="hud" as="hud" template="page/html/hud.phtml">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>

</layout>
```

[image]

**Created new Links template based on code of top.links, and referred to this in the HUD's block as follows.**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <!-- Here is where we edit the header block -->
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="top.links" />
            <remove name="top.search" />
            <!-- This is the block that holds the HUD -->
            <block type="page/html" name="hud" as="hud" template="page/html/hud.phtml">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="hud.links" as="hudLinks" template="page/template/hudLinks.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>

</layout>
```

Below is hud.phtml

```
<!-- hud.phtml -->
<div id="hud">
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hudLinks') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top.search') ?> 
</div>
```

This brings the most interesting results. I can see the template is found but nothing appears.

[image]

I really am clueless with this. Am I doing something completely wrong here? For what it's worth, here is the code I'm using for hudLinks.phtml and the top.links template.

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with editing `page.xml` if it's your own theme.

Comment: The theme I have started with basically uses the page.xml file in the base of Magento. I've tried overriding this with using a page.xml file within my own theme's layout folder but it didn't seem to work. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"remove" rules are processed at the end, I think, so you have to change the name of the block you are inserting.
Now look how a link is added:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
51:        <reference name="top.links">
52-            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
53-        </reference>
```

The link are added to the block named top.links. That's why your new block is empty.
Solution: search xml files for occurences of top.links , and add the code you find to your local.xml file.

Comment: I have already copied and pasted the exact same code from other xml files when using this instance. I will try the code you've provided above and comment back. Thanks for your response greg0ire.

Comment: @Liam Spencer : after copying and pasting the code, make sure you adapth the name attribute of your reference tag to match the name of your newly created block.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. This seems to have worked for me and has maybe helped me understand the Magento system a bit more. I'm sure I'll be asking more questions here in future! Thanks again!